# Jquery TypeError: $(...).roundabout is not a function

Tags: jquery

I have error message in firebug as:

> TypeError: $(...).roundabout is not a function.

This is happening only when I add the **$('#getarea')...** statement below. I want to execute two statements when change function happens (hope this works).

The first statement is working fine and for second statement, response from getarea.php is good as I can see valid data but it is not populating into **#getarea**.

#getarea is a DIV element and when I view this element is 'View source', it is showing in RED, not sure if this means something.

Sorry, I was unable to past the entire code as it is huge. Please advise.

```
$('#selcity').change(function(event)
{
    $('#selarea').removeClass("hidden");
    $('#getarea').load('getarea.php?city='+encodeURIComponent($('#selcity').val() ) );
});
```

Comment: TypeError: $(...).roundabout is not a function
[Break On This Error]  

minOpacity: 1

Comment: Seems like part of your code is using the [jQuery roundabout plugin](http://fredhq.com/projects/roundabout/). Is it included?

Comment: yes, there is <script type="text/javascript" src="js/roundabout.js"></script>

Comment: Do you have any 404 errors in your network console?

Comment: only one error in console - TypeError: $(...).roundabout is not a function
[Break On This Error]  

minOpacity: 1

Answer (score -1):

Just add `var $ = jQuery.noConflict();`

Comment: There's nothing in the question that indicates a $ conflict. While this certainly could be the cause, it's a wild guess. Unclear questions should be closed or clarified.